# 20.04 - does not detect VGA monitor connection event

Tags: nvidia, monitor, vga

It's my first question here - so I'd like to say Hello!

I'm facing some issue on such setup:

- Dell Precision 7510 with origin Nvidia graphics
- Ubuntu 20.04 fresh install
- Dell docking station with external monitor (over VGA).

Issue?
When I connect or disconnect laptop from docking station, there is no change in active screens.
If I plug docking station while the monitor is in standby mode, it does not wake up.

Observations:

- When I connect docking station, I have only one desktop.
- When I go to display settings (or just type "xrandr") system suddenly detects the second monitor (my primary laptop screen goes black for a moment, second monitor is waking up from sleep) and now I have two desktops to use.
- When I have two desktops and I disconnect laptop from docking station, system does not detect this and I still have two desktop (I can move mouse pointer over the place I did't see!)
- As last time, opening the display setting (or issuing "xrandr") triggers refresh and now I have one desktop.
- When my second monitor is detected (after xrandr) somehow all my opened applications are moving to the second monitor (like it will be some kind of primary display?)
- I run windows from second drive on the same setup, it works correctly.
- I have second laptop (DELL E7440) with the same Ubuntu 20.04 - it works also OK.

What I tried?

- I opened Software&Updates, and switched in "Additional Drivers" from X.Org server to Nvidia driver 390, 450, 460. It did not work.

Output from "xrandr":

- When docking station was not connected:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  48.00  
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

- When docking station connected:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1200     59.95 +
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  48.00  
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Sounds more like an issue with the docking station. Have you looked into that?

Comment: I did not dive into details yet, I assumed that it is OK since it is working with second laptop and with the same laptop under Windows.